# Javascript Regex For Comma Delimited String

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex expression that performs a "contains" function on a input/type=hidden field's value.  This hidden field stores unique values in a comma delimited string.

Here's a scenario.
The value: "mix" needs to be added to the hidden field.  It will only be added if it does not exist as a comma delimited value.

With my limited knowlege of regex, I can't prevent the search from returning all ocurrences of the "mix" value. For example if: hiddenField.val = 'mixer, mixon, mixx', the regex always returns true, because the all three words contain the "mix" characters.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\b` metacharacter to set word boundaries:

```
var word = "mix";
new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b").test(hidden.value);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ztYff/

---

**UPDATE.** In order to protect our regular expression of possible problems when using variable instead of hardcoding (see comments below), we need to escape special characters in `word` variable. [One possible solution](http://simonwillison.net/2006/jan/20/escape/) is to use the following method:

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ztYff/1/

---

**UPDATE 2.** Following [@Porco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10858113/1249581) we can combine regular expressions and string splitting to get another universal solution:

```
hidden.value.split(/\s*,\s*/).indexOf(word) != -1;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ztYff/2/

Comment: This is not a good idea. You really should regex-quote the `word` to avoid run-time errors.

Comment: @Tomalak Not really got what you mean. Could you give an example.

Comment: What if `word` contains a backslash? Or a dollar sign? This will break your solution. (Not in this special case, but generally when you build regex from strings.)

Comment: @Tomalak Ah... well, it will break any universal solution like this. Of course, word should be secured. Let me think about the better way.

Comment: @Tomalak Now regexp should be protected.

Comment: Very well, that's much better. +1

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everyone.  I think VisioN has the best solution for dealing with a variety of input strings.  Thanks Tomalak for steering us to the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
hiddenField.val.split(',').indexOf('mix') >= 0
```

Could also use a regex(startofstring OR comma + mix + endofstring OR comma):

```
hiddenField.val.match(/(,|^)mix($|,)/)
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` is only supported in IE9 though.

Comment: the MDN has a backwards-compatible implementation of `indexOf()` for browsers that are missing it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: added regex for alternative method

Comment: I like the simplicity of your answer. I'll need to do some performance tests to see if the two operations: split and indexOf will perform faster than a single regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
hiddenField.val.match(/^(mix)[^,]*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/(^|,)\s*mix\s*(,|$)/.test(field.value)
```

It matches `mix`, either if it is at the beginning of a string or at the end or in between commas. If each entry in the list can consist of multiple words, you might want to remove the `\s*`.